# long double in fabs, range and overflow errors

Tags: c

At [wiki.sei.cmu.edu](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/FLP34-C.+Ensure+that+floating-point+conversions+are+within+range+of+the+new+type), they claim the following code is error-free for out-of-range floating-point errors during assignment; I've narrowed it down to the `long double` case:

> #### Compliant Solution (Narrowing Conversion)
>
> This compliant solution checks whether the values to be stored can be represented in the new type:

```c
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
  
void func(double d_a, long double big_d) {
  double d_b;

  // ...

  if (big_d != 0.0 &&
      (isnan(big_d) ||
       isgreater(fabs(big_d), DBL_MAX) ||
       isless(fabs(big_d), DBL_MIN))) {
    /* Handle error */
  } else {
    d_b = (double)big_d;
  } 
}
```

Unless I'm missing something, the declaration of `fabs` according to the C99 and C11 standards is `double fabs(double x)`, which means it takes a `double`, so this code isn't compliant, and instead `long double fabsl(long double x)` should be used.

Further, I believe `isgreater` and `isless` should be declared as taking a `long double` as their first parameters (since that's what `fabsl` returns).

---

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    long double ld = 1.12345e506L;

    printf("%lg\n", fabs(ld));  // UB: ld is outside the range of double (~ 1e308)
    printf("%Lg\n", fabsl(ld)); // OK

    return 0;
}
```

On my machine, this produces the following output:

```
inf
1.12345e+506
```

along with a warning (GCC):

```c
warning: conversion from 'long double' to 'double' may change value [-Wfloat-conversion]
     printf("%lg\n", fabs(ld));
                          ^~
```

Am I therefore correct in saying their code results in undefined behavior?

On p. 211 of the C99 standard there's a footnote that reads:

> Particularly on systems with wide expression evaluation, a `<math.h>` function might pass arguments
> and return values in wider format than the synopsis prototype indicates.

and on some systems `long double` has the exact same value range, representation, etc. as `double`, but this doesn't mean the code above is portable.

---

Now I have a related question here, and I'd just like to ask for confirmation (I've read through dozens of questions and answers here, but I'm still a little confused because they often deal with specific examples and specific types, not all of them are sourced, or they're about C++, and I think it'd be a waste of time to ask each of these questions as a separate, "formal" question on Stack Overflow): according to the C99 and C11 standards, there's a difference between *overflow*, which occurs during an arithmetic operation, and a *range error*, which occurs when a value is too large to be represented in a given type. I've provided excerpts from the C99 standard that talk about this, and I'd appreciate it if someone could confirm that my interpretation is correct. (I'm aware of the fact that certain implementations define what happens when *undefined behavior* occurs, e.g. as explained [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.63/html_node/Integer-Overflow-Basics.html), but that's not what I'm interested in right now.)

- for *floating-point* types, overflow results in some representation of a "large value" (i.e. as defined by the `HUGE_VAL*` macro definition as per 7.12.1):

> A floating result overflows if the magnitude of the mathematical result is finite but so
> large that the mathematical result cannot be represented without extraordinary roundoff
> error in an object of the specified type. If a floating result overflows and default rounding
> is in effect, or if the mathematical result is an exact infinity (for example `log(0.0)`),
> then the function returns the value of the macro `HUGE_VAL`, `HUGE_VALF`, or `HUGE_VALL` according to the return type, with the same sign as the correct value of the
> function;

On my system, `HUGE_VAL*` is defined as `INFINITY` cast to the appropriate floating-point type.

So this is completely **legal**, the value of `HUGE_VAL*` being implementation-defined or something like that notwithstanding.

- for *floating-point* types, a range error results in **undefined behavior** (6.3.1.5):

> When a `double` is demoted to `float`, a `long double` is demoted to `double` or
> `float`, or a value being represented in greater precision and range than required by its
> semantic type (see 6.3.1.8) is explicitly converted to its semantic type [...]. If the value being converted is outside the range of values that can be represented, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: (a) Yes, passing a `long double` argument for a `double` parameter (for `fabs` or other functions) results in undefined behavior per 6.3.1.5 if the value is out of range. (b) You seem to be asking primarily about floating-point conversions, so I do not see why you discuss or quote anything about conversions to integer. If there are multiple questions, you should clarify them and possibly ask them them in separate questions.

Comment: Another error in the code is that being less than `DBL_MIN` does not mean the value is out of range. It may even be exactly representable, as a subnormal number.

Comment: long double is 80 bits, double is 64 bit. long double is an x86 extension in GCC, AFAIK, and 80 bits is required for 64 bit precision inside the x86 architecture... so unless you absolutely positively depend upon that extra resolution.... cast to double and move on.

Comment: @Jimmio92: The C standard requires `long double` to exist but says only that it needs to at least be able to represent every `double`.  On x86 it's usually 80 bits (but less efficient than `double` because it's only supported by legacy x87 instructions).  On some others it's an alias of `double`.  On yet others it's a full 128 bits.